# Best practice for modifying a python (turtle) object inside a function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Inside functions, I learned somewhere to work on copies of the arguments, for example: `list_arg --> t = list_arg[:]`. It made sense, so I try to do it consistently.

Now I am going again through the basics of programming, with the help of Think Python 2nd Edition by Allen B. Downey. In **chapter 4 - Case study: interface design**, I have to draw polygons with the help of the turtle module

```
import turtle

def mysquare(length, turtle_obj):
    t = turtle_obj
    t.pd()
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(90)
    t.pu()

def main():
    bob = turtle.Turtle()
    mysquare(100, bob)
    turtle.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this case, `bob` and `t` refer to the same turtle object. If I forget to make it hold the pen up `t.pu()` in the `mysquare` function, `bob` will (potentially) keep drawing in the `main` function.

As much as I would like to keep the programming style of writing functions that don't change their parameters, I don't know if it makes any sense in this situation.

1. Is there a general way, best practice to handle such a situation?
2. Conceptually, does my issue have to do with a particular programming paradigm (object-oriented, functional), or a language style (pythonic way)?

Comment: Generally, functions shouldn't mutate their inputs.

Comment: In general, you just need to document what `mysquare` does, including what state it will leave `turtle_obj` in. That serves two purposes: it tells the user what to expect, and it helps you test that `mysquare` works the way it is supposed to. If you forget `t.pu()`, then that's a bug to fix like any other bug.

Answer (score 0):

We can correct for the pen state on the way out using turtle's `isdown()` method:

```
import turtle

def mysquare(length, turtle_obj):
    if was_up := not turtle_obj.isdown():
        turtle_obj.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle_obj.forward(length)
        turtle_obj.left(90)

    if was_up:
        turtle_obj.penup()


turtle.penup()
mysquare(50, turtle)
turtle.goto(100, 100)
mysquare(25, turtle)

turtle.done()
```

The calls to `mysquare()` will return the pen state to what it was when the function was called.  Assigning `turtle_obj` to `t` achieves nothing.

Comment: Assigning `turtle_obj` to `t` achieves nothing. I know, I am experimenting to find my programming style: in this case I can understand from the function arguments what I am dealing with (a turtle object), whereas `t` in the function body is compact enough to let me focus on what the function does. I cannot say I am fully convinced by this style, but that's part of experimenting, I guess